# Rewrite XML resulting tree by adding and rearranging nodes with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to rewrite a set of `<p>` and `<lb>` nodes. This is my initial node set:

```
<p>
    text[1] and nodes[1] here
    <pb/>
    text[2] and nodes[2] here
    <pb/>
    text[3] and nodes[3] here
    <pb/>
    [...]
    text[x] and any nodes[x] here
</p>
```

And this is what I need:

```
<p>text[1] and nodes[1] here</p>
<pb/>
<p>text[2] and nodes[2] here</p>
<pb/>
<p>text[3] and nodes[3] here</p>
<pb/>
<p>[...]</p>
<p>text[x] and nodes[x] here</p>
```

I managed to rewrite the first and last nodes and texts by butting them in variables for further transformation:

```
<xsl:variable name="textAndNotes_1">
    <p>
         <xsl:copy-of select=" child::node()[not( preceding-sibling::*:pb)
         and not(self::*:pb)]"/>
    </p>
</xsl:variable>

[...]

<xsl:variable name="textAndNotes_x">
    <p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()[not(following-sibling::*:pb) and  
        not(self::*:pb)]"/>
    </p>
</xsl:variable>
```

This also works for first and last `<pb/>`. But I am stack with the internal `<p>...</p>` and internal `<pb/>` and I am not sure this is the right way to do it. I have been searching for hours without finding the answer. Any help?

All best, Tristan

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes I can use XSLT 2.0. Thanks in advance... T

Comment: Is `[...]` the real content you don't want to wrap into a `p` element? Can you explain which content is supposed to be wrapped into a `p` element and which not?

Comment: Sorry for this. `[...]` can contain additional `<pb/>` + other node and text elements. The other node and text elements  would also have to be wrapped into `<p></p>` nodes. So basically every element before and after the different `<pb/>` nodes has to be wrapped in `<p></p>`.

Comment: Then please edit your question and correct the samples, currently in the output `[...]` is not wrapped.

Comment: "*So basically every element before and after the different <pb/> nodes has to be wrapped in <p></p>*" That's not clear at all. If the breaking `<pb/>` node can appear *anywhere*, then this gets **much** more complicated, since you will have to close all the ancestor nodes and create duplicate ones on the other side of the divide.

Comment: Please spell out what `[...]` looks really like and why it ends up in a `p` elements of its own and not together with the `text[x] and nodes[x] here` contents.

Comment: Yes indeed, and I cannot find a way to match the text and nodes between the `<pb/>` nodes of my initial `<p></p>`. I know however that all `<pb/>` nodes are children of the initial `<p></p>`.

Comment: @Tristan It's still not clear what the `[...]` stands for and why it gets its own `p` wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="pb">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::pb)]" />
        </p>    
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <p>
        text[1] and nodes[1] here
        <pb/>
        text[2] and nodes[2] here
        <pb/>
        text[3] and nodes[3] here
        <pb/>
        [...]
        text[x] and any nodes[x] here
    </p>
</root>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <p>
        text[1] and nodes[1] here
        </p>
   <p>
        text[2] and nodes[2] here
        </p>
   <p>
        text[3] and nodes[3] here
        </p>
   <p>
        [...]
        text[x] and any nodes[x] here
    </p>
</root>
```

Note that this assumes all `<pb/>` dividers are direct children of `p`.

Comment: Why are there no `<pb/>` in the result? The requested output in the question contains them.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  It does? I worked hard at removing them. Anyway, it's an easy fix to retain them. But OP needs to clarify first.

Comment: This works like a charm. I had not think of `<xsl:for-each-group/>` which solved the problem. Just had to add a tiny `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[self::pb]"/>` for the `<pb/>`. Thanks so much, Michael !!!

Comment: @Tristan You only needed to remove the `[not(self::pb)]` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledege level of XSL, it comes out a little complex XSL, but here it is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
<root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
</root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <!--Counts the number of groups and calls the iterator template-->
    <xsl:call-template name="print-all-groups"><xsl:with-param name="numgroups" select="count(pb)"/><xsl:with-param name="index" select="0"/></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="print-all-groups">
    <!--Iterates the child groups of P: from the index-th to the numgroups-th-->
    <xsl:param name="numgroups"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="index"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:call-template name="print-group"><xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index"></xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:if test="$index &lt; $numgroups">
        <xsl:call-template name="print-all-groups"><xsl:with-param name="numgroups" select="$numgroups"/><xsl:with-param name="index" select="1+$index"/></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="print-group">
    <!--Selects the first node after the index-th group and processes it (applies the 'group-item' templates)-->
    <xsl:param name="index"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:if test="$index=0">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates select="(text()|*)[1]" mode="group-item"></xsl:apply-templates></p>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($index=0)">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates select="(pb[$index]/following-sibling::text()|pb[$index]/following-sibling::*)[1]" mode="group-item"></xsl:apply-templates></p>
    </xsl:if>
    <pb/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="group-item">
    <!--Copies the current node and iterates to the following sibling until a PB is found-->
    <xsl:if test="name(.) !='pb'">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(following-sibling::text()|following-sibling::*)[1]" mode="group-item"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="group-item">
    <!--Copies the current node and iterates to the following sibling-->
    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="(following-sibling::text()|following-sibling::*)[1]" mode="group-item"></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only 'trick' is that it *always* prints a `<pb>` node after each group. Is it wrong?

I've tested it with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <p>
        text1<month>january</month><day>monday</day>
        <pb/>
        text2<month>february</month><day>tuesday</day>
        <pb/>
        text3<month>march</month><day>wednesday</day>
    </p>
</root>
```

... and it produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<p>
        text1<month>january</month>
<day>monday</day>
</p>
<pb/>
<p>
        text2<month>february</month>
<day>tuesday</day>
</p>
<pb/>
<p>
        text3<month>march</month>
<day>wednesday</day>
</p>
<pb/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Martin's solution is a bit less dense but I will keep this strategy in mind for other situations.

Comment: Yes, it's a little dense, I know... :-) You are welcome.